# Performance of whereHas laravel

Tags: laravel

I have read many articles warning about whereHas(it use subquery in where exists) performance when the data is big(Here: [18415](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18415), [5328](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5328), ...). In my case below will I need to replace it? And how?.
Table products

```
+----+---------------------+
| id |     created_at      |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2020-10-10 10:10:10 |
|  2 | 2020-10-10 10:10:10 |
+----+---------------------+
```

Table product_translations(indexes: map_id, language_code, slug)

```
+----+--------+---------------+-----------+-----------+
| id | map_id | language_code |   name    |   slug    |
+----+--------+---------------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |      1 | en            | name en 1 | name-en-1 |
|  2 |      1 | es            | name es 1 | name-es-1 |
|  3 |      2 | en            | name en 2 | name-en-2 |
|  4 |      2 | es            | name es 2 | name-es-2 |
+----+--------+---------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Product.php

```
function translation(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\ProductTranslation', 'map_id', 'id');
}
```

ProductController.php

```
function view($slug){
    $currentItem = Product::with(['translation' => function($q) use($slug){
            $q->where(['slug' => $slug, 'language_code' => \App::getLocale()]);
        }])->whereHas('translation', function($q) use ($slug){
            $q->where(['slug' => $slug, 'language_code' => \App::getLocale()]);
        })
    if ($currentItem == null) {
        abort(404);
    }
    return view('product.view', compact('currentItem'));
}
```

I'm using laravel 8x.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `whereHas` with `whereIn`.

```php
$currentItem = Product::with(['translation' => function($q) use($slug){
    $q->where(['slug' => $slug, 'language_code' => \App::getLocale()]);
}])->whereIn(
    'id',
    ProductTranslation::select('map_id')
        ->where(['slug' => $slug, 'language_code' => \App::getLocale()])
);
```

Select the foreign key from a subselect and uses it with where in.